# status="NotProcessed" for EnhancedAirBookRQ API

Tags: sabre

Can anyone help me in this regard, checking with Sabre Soap API's for booking flow. I am getting the failure in **EnhancedAirBookRQ** response.

I am getting the below response :

```
<ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01">
    <Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-10-01T05:38:45.063-05:00">
        <SystemSpecificResults>
            <Message code="ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">*NO FARES/RBD/CARRIER</Message>
            <Message code="146">*NO FARES/RBD/CARRIER</Message>
        </SystemSpecificResults>
    </Error>
</ApplicationResults>
```

Request:

```
<v3:EnhancedAirBookRQ version="3.2.0" HaltOnError="true" IgnoreOnError="true">
  <v3:OTA_AirBookRQ>
    <v3:OriginDestinationInformation>
      <v3:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2018-11-11T07:38:00" DepartureDateTime="2018-11-11T06:31:00" FlightNumber="6384" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
        <v3:DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOS" />
        <v3:Equipment AirEquipType="E90" />
        <v3:MarketingAirline Code="TP" FlightNumber="6384" />
        <v3:MarriageGrp Ind="false" />
        <v3:OperatingAirline Code="B6" />
        <v3:OriginLocation LocationCode="JFK" />
      </v3:FlightSegment>
      <v3:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2018-11-12T06:00:00" DepartureDateTime="2018-11-11T18:40:00" FlightNumber="218" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
        <v3:DestinationLocation LocationCode="LIS" />
        <v3:Equipment AirEquipType="332" />
        <v3:MarketingAirline Code="TP" FlightNumber="218" />
        <v3:MarriageGrp Ind="true" />
        <v3:OperatingAirline Code="TP" />
        <v3:OriginLocation LocationCode="BOS" />
      </v3:FlightSegment>
      <v3:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2018-11-12T12:20:00" DepartureDateTime="2018-11-12T08:40:00" FlightNumber="6791" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
        <v3:DestinationLocation LocationCode="LUX" />
        <v3:Equipment AirEquipType="73H" />
        <v3:MarketingAirline Code="TP" FlightNumber="6791" />
        <v3:MarriageGrp Ind="true" />
        <v3:OperatingAirline Code="LG" />
        <v3:OriginLocation LocationCode="LIS" />
      </v3:FlightSegment>
      <v3:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2018-11-15T12:25:00" DepartureDateTime="2018-11-15T10:55:00" FlightNumber="3761" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="X" Status="NN">
        <v3:DestinationLocation LocationCode="OPO" />
        <v3:Equipment AirEquipType="73W" />
        <v3:MarketingAirline Code="LG" FlightNumber="3761" />
        <v3:MarriageGrp Ind="false" />
        <v3:OperatingAirline Code="LG" />
        <v3:OriginLocation LocationCode="LUX" />
      </v3:FlightSegment>
      <v3:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2018-11-15T15:30:00" DepartureDateTime="2018-11-15T14:30:00" FlightNumber="1947" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="W" Status="NN">
        <v3:DestinationLocation LocationCode="LIS" />
        <v3:Equipment AirEquipType="AT7" />
        <v3:MarketingAirline Code="TP" FlightNumber="1947" />
        <v3:MarriageGrp Ind="false" />
        <v3:OperatingAirline Code="WI" />
        <v3:OriginLocation LocationCode="OPO" />
      </v3:FlightSegment>
      <v3:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2018-11-15T20:00:00" DepartureDateTime="2018-11-15T17:00:00" FlightNumber="209" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="W" Status="NN">
        <v3:DestinationLocation LocationCode="JFK" />
        <v3:Equipment AirEquipType="332" />
        <v3:MarketingAirline Code="TP" FlightNumber="209" />
        <v3:MarriageGrp Ind="true" />
        <v3:OperatingAirline Code="TP" />
        <v3:OriginLocation LocationCode="LIS" />
      </v3:FlightSegment>
    </v3:OriginDestinationInformation>
  </v3:OTA_AirBookRQ>
  <v3:OTA_AirPriceRQ>
    <!--v3:PriceComparison /-->
    <v3:PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
      <v3:OptionalQualifiers>
        <v3:PricingQualifiers>
          <v3:PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
        </v3:PricingQualifiers>
      </v3:OptionalQualifiers>
    </v3:PriceRequestInformation>
  </v3:OTA_AirPriceRQ>
  <v3:PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" />
  <v3:PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false" />
</v3:EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

Checking this test step in soap ui project given by Sabre on their developer portal. Before this, checked for test-steps for create session and low fare search for flights.
Can anyone tell any way to resolve on this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you please share xml request as well

Comment: @Sheheryar Aamir, updated with request xml

Comment: can you search again for these sectors using any sabre flight search api to see if information provided in EnhancedAirBookRQ flight detail is correct.

Answer (score 1):

EnhancedAirBookRQ flight details are not correct. Please verify or use search API again to fetch correct details